# Where to initialize struct for multiple instances in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, instance-variables

I'm making a task-sharing app where you can share multiple lists of tasks with multiple individuals (like one with your spouse, one with your kid, etc.). Each list's data source is a struct called `TaskList`, so I will have multiple instances of `TaskList`. Where should I initialize those instances?

I'm new at this and any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code for the `UITableViewController` that creates the task list using struct TaskList:

```
import UIKit

class LoLFirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }

    @IBAction func cancelToLoLFirstTableViewController(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

    @IBAction func saveAddTask(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let AddTaskTableViewController = segue.source as? AddTaskTableViewController {

            if let task = AddTaskTableViewController.task {
                tasks.append(task)

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tasks.count-1, section: 0)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
            cell.task = task

        if cell.accessoryView == nil {
            let cb = CheckButton()
            cb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.accessoryView = cb
        }
        let cb = cell.accessoryView as! CheckButton
        cb.check(tasks[indexPath.row].completed)

        return cell
    }

    func buttonTapped(_ target:UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        guard let touch = event.allTouches?.first else { return }
        let point = touch.location(in: self.tableView)
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)

        var tappedItem = tasks[indexPath!.row] as Task
        tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed
        tasks[indexPath!.row] = tappedItem

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    }
}
```

This is the code for TaskList:

```
import UIKit

struct TaskList {
   var buddy: String
   var phoneNumber: String
   var tasks: [Task]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First option.** You can create some kind of manager and store that list in that object:

```
class TaskListsManager
{
  var taskLists:[TaskList] = []
}
```

And then pass instance of that object between your viewcontrollers:

```
let taskListsManager = TaskListsManager()

firstViewController.taskListsManager = taskListsManager
secondViewController.taskListsManager = taskListsManager
```

**Second option** would be to create a singleton object:

```
class TaskListsManager
{
  static let sharedInstance = TaskListsManager()

  var taskLists:[TaskList] = []
}
```

And you can use it anywhere in your app:

```
let first = TaskListsManager.sharedInstance.taskLists.first
```

Comment: I'm a little more comfortable with the TaskListsManager approach, so that's the one I'm implementing now. What's the purpose of the following lines? To update the data in taskListsManager once it's been changed?

    firstViewController.taskListsManager = tasksListsManager
    secondViewController.taskListsManager = taskListsManager

Comment: @BobF. sort of. In case you want to have only one instance of manager, you will have to pass it between viewcontrollers. So you create one instance of TaskListsManager  when your app starts, and then pass it to your first viewconteroller, then if you need to navigate to another viewcontroller you pass your manager instance from the first controller to second. Data update is a different question, for this purpose you can use notifications (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) or protocols/delegates.

Comment: @Nikita_Gaydukov Ah, ok. So then these lines should be in the TaskListsManager object? Or in the UITableViewController? Because if I put them in the UITableViewController I get an "Unresolved Identifier 'tasks'" error everywhere that 'tasks' appears.
let taskListsManager = TaskListsManager()

firstViewController.taskListsManager = taskListsManager
secondViewController.taskListsManager = taskListsManager

Comment: @BobF. Not really. Take a look at the complete example: https://pastebin.com/PZ6i7SHf

Comment: @Nikita_Gaydukov Wow, that was very helpful! Now I understand. I appreciate your taking the time to write that out, Nikita :)

Comment: @BobF. Glad it helped. Please accept the answer if you think it was helpful.

Comment: In the pastebin example there's an ellipsis in the line: if let newViewController = storyboard?.instantiate(...) as? LoLSecondTableViewController. What am I supposed to put in place of the ellipsis? Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Would that be the Identifier of a new separate view controller in the storyboard? Because right now I only have the one UITableViewController in the storyboard. Also, I never created a "storyboard" variable. Do I then need to do that in LoLFirstViewController?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass there a storyboard id for your second viewcontroller.

Comment: storyboard variable is a property of UIViewController, so you don't need to create it. You LoLFirstViewController should already have it.